# Unbalanced and not fully responsive grids in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, responsive-design

I am trying to put three grid inside a div and make it responsive. But couldn't manage it properly. Grids have some balance problems. the first grid has a image. And the second(center) grid has a text. The last one(third) grid will have a button.

When I try to make browser smaller or connect from phone. The grids are not getting balanced and not responsive. What am I doing wrong here? I really appreciate any help! Thank you.

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #636b6f;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", 'lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.banner-back-ground {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f6fa;
}

h1 {
    color: #4CAF50;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-back-ground {
    background-color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

img {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.all-content-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.all-content-wrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 20%; margin: auto; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 60%; margin: auto; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 20%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

.content-text ul {
    background-color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content-text li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner-back-ground">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>BEN</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-back-ground">
            <div class="row">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#home">東北</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">関西</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">北海道</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">関東</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>　検査</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="all-content-wrapper group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/130x130/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                        <span class="content-text">
                            <ul>
                                <li>asldkas;ldka;sldka;sdlka;sdlka;sdja;sdjasdjlakjsdlakjsdlakjddasdasdsa</li>
                                <li>sdlalsdka;sdkad</li>
                                <li>;alskda;slkda;lsdkasd</li>
                                <li>alksd:a;sklda;ksda;sdk;askd</li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_3_of_3">
                        Here Button
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

As you see on snippet navigatior bar and inside of div are not very respensive...

Comment: well the image is a fixed width so it will not grow/shrink with the column

Comment: your code is responsive, as @epascarello, it's just the image that's causing the issue that you might feel it's not responsive. And also try using Flex, that's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #636b6f;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", 'lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.banner-back-ground {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f6fa;
}

h1 {
    color: #4CAF50;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-back-ground {
    background-color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

img {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.all-content-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.all-content-wrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
/* flex layout with wrap for ease of achieving responsive design */
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    /* don't need float with flex - float:left; */
    /* specify grow, shrink and basis width */
    flex:0 0 auto;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 20%; margin: auto; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 60%; margin: auto; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 20%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

.content-text ul {
    background-color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content-text li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner-back-ground">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>BEN</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-back-ground">
            <div class="row">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#home">東北</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">関西</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">北海道</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">関東</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>　検査</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="all-content-wrapper group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/130x130/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                        <span class="content-text">
                            <ul>
                                <li>asldkas;ldka;sldka;sdlka;sdlka;sdja;sdjasdjlakjsdlakjsdlakjddasdasdsa</li>
                                <li>sdlalsdka;sdkad</li>
                                <li>;alskda;slkda;lsdkasd</li>
                                <li>alksd:a;sklda;ksda;sdk;askd</li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_3_of_3">
                        Here Button
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```